# Pipeline from Azure DevOps to local domain through a VPN and AD server

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure-devops, vpn

We have a VPN server in AWS which is also a AD domain controller that controls our local domain (private subnet) in AWS.
We want to create a pipeline from Azure DevOps through VPN server (Which is also a AD Domain controller) to our other server and deploy the project on the server on private subnet.

So my question is, Can we do any of the things mentioned below? and if yes how can we achieve it?:

- Is there a way to make Azure DevOps to use VPN connection to connect directly to server on private subnet? and is it secure?
- Is there a way after adding the server on the private subnet to the server list in AD Domain controller server and create a pipeline to the AD server but tell the AD server to deploy it on other server listed in the Server Management?

Comment: Do you mean "Azure DevOps" (as in, the Azure DevOps platform), or "an Azure Pipelines agent"?

Comment: @DanielMann We have a repo in Azure DevOps platform and want to create pipeline from that repo's main branch.

Comment: That did not answer my question. "Azure DevOps" is the service. It has various APIs and a web-front end. "Azure Pipelines" is a subset of those services. Azure Pipelines uses a piece of software called a "pipeline agent" to run continuous integration and continuous delivery processes. The agent is a separate piece of software that **communicates** with Azure DevOps. Are your networking requirements for the **service**, or the **agent software**?

Comment: @DanielMann Sorry for that. I am trying to use the agent.

Comment: Hi @AfshinMobayenKhiabani, if the provided answer resolved your issue, you may mark it as answer or upvote it so that others who encounter the similar issue, it may be useful for them or community members.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

•   Yes, there is a way through which we can ***connect Azure DevOps to the AD Domain controller server which itself is the VPN server in AWS***. For that purpose, you will have to ***ensure that your AD Domain controller server or VPN server is accessible from the internet and since it is hosted on AWS, consider it to be hosted on on-premises environment for this solution perspective***. Thus, I would suggest you ***deploy Azure DevOps agents and agent pools such that they deploy artifacts and other required data to the ADDC or VPN server in AWS as they should have ‘line of sight’ connectivity to the VPN server since access to internet is needed for these agents to connect to Azure pipelines as shown in the below diagram***.

Also, `rather than hosted agent pools which are used for Azure resources in the virtual network on Azure itself, use default agents which need to be configured for on-premises environment`.

[image: DevOps agents schematic diagram]

•   Since ***Azure DevOps agents communicate with the VPN servers in AWS as stated above, you can further create route tables between the private subnet and the subnet in which VPN is hosted in AWS as well as whitelist the IP address of the connecting VPN gateway and related resources in that VPC***. Also, `peering between the different VPCs if private subnets are hosted in it can also work by configuring the proper route tables and allowing the appropriate IP addresses in AWS`.

Kindly find the documentation link below which describes the details on the configuration of DevOps agents as stated above: -

***https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/pools-queues?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbrowser***

**For additional security, you can also deploy your DevOps agents behind a web proxy** as below: -

***https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/proxy?view=azure-devops&tabs=windows***